# How to replace elements of Python lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

This is quite a basic question

*I want to replace the elements of a list, by that of another list.*

This is my code:

```
listb = ['1','2','3','4']
lista = ['a','b','c','d']
print listb
print "\n\n"
listb = listb.replace(listb[0],lista[0])
print listb
```

This is wrong. How can I do it correctly...?

Comment: `This is wrong. How can I do it correctly` - What are you trying to do?

Comment: `listb[0] = lista[0]` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Your line `listb = listb.replace(listb[0],lista[0])` is wrong as `replace` is not a function of `list`

You need to instead do

```
listb = [i for i in lista]
```

This will replace each of the values of `listb` with that of `lista`.

If you want to replace a single value, you need to do

```
listb[0] = lista[0]
```

Note -

You can also do to copy the entire list

```
import copy
listb = copy.deepcopy(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace one element in `listb` with an element in `lista`, then

```
listb[0] = lista[0]
```

should take you there.

If you want to replace each of elements in `listb` with the one with the same index in `lista` without creating a new list, then

```
for index, value in enumerate(listb):
    list[index] = lista[index]
```

is what you want.

If you just want `listb` to be a copy of `lista`, then

```
import copy
listb = copy.deepcopy(lista)
```

is the answer.

Comment: Voting up your answer because it gives the original poster all the three options! Good answer. keep it up.